# I got this error failed to :http://premieroptie.nl/wp-content/themes/theme51771/favicon.ico load resource: net: :ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, php, javaquery

when I open my website url is : computertechnet.nl and then right click on it inspect  and the when I go to console tab  I see this error:

> failed to :http://premieroptie.nl/wp-content/themes/theme51771/favicon.ico  load resource: net: :ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

I see also second warning:

> Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired:                    util.js:32
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

how I can solve this 2  problems?
I have changed my domain name from `premieroptie.nl` to `computertechnet.nl` everything with old URL is cleaned by my provider and by me. There is no directory in my ftp server either in PhpMyAdmin with this old URL name I have just also cleaned `favicon.ico` from theme51771 . I don't need it .
thanks
johan

Comment: Did you update Wordpress to use the new domain name? Also the second one is telling you that you are using a parameter that is [no longer needed for Google Maps Javascript Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required), it references `util.js` so edit your js to not use the sensor parameter

Comment: 1-yes I updated , I deleted also favicon from my website on ftp server.  but this warning stil exists , how I can solve this problem?                                 2-I have wordpres theme in which map(name) exactly I have to edit js and where exactly in the map and whice code I have to insert in it?

Answer (score 0):

Your website favicon is linked with other website::http://premieroptie.nl/wp-content/themes/theme51771 that cant find resource of icon there, remove the favicon in your website

Comment: I removed the favicon , there is no where this old domain name besides here, and I don't understand why(it is all removed this old domain name in database by my provider and by me)? how I can remove it , is there any php map which has to be edited?